# Using wordpress as an article directory - what plugins/themes to use?

Tags: wordpress

Anybody using wordpress as an article directory?  I don't have time to customize it, so if anybody has done it or using any plugin/theme could you point me to it?

Also, is there any alternative script for article directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use article directory plugin + theme (optional, you can always build your own theme)

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/article-directory/

Theme: http://articlesss.com/article-directory-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does this right out of the box. Article Directory... Blog... it's all the same. Figure out your topics/categories and file your posts/articles accordingly. Happy content publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking for a decent directory script for WP myself and never really found anything that was better than merely average.

Your question finally got me motivated enough to make a big list of them, so [I made a big post on my blog today with a heap of link index / article site scripts](http://affmktg.com/202/tools/article-listing-link-directory-content-management-scripts/).

Surprisingly I found a pretty decent article/directory solution for wordpress when I was nearly finished. That being said, after looking at dozens and dozens of link/article scripts today, I think there's betters solutions than WP if you're serious about that sort of site.

WSN links, and the article script that same company makes would be my personal choice. The problem with those sorts of sites (compared to a personal blog) is that you're suddenly dealing with lots of other webmasters changing things around on you, so you've really got to have decent tools to check links and make sure it's all OK and what you linked to originally, otherwise you're going to lose surfers.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get Teasers or Excerpts on into any sidebars you can use the [Category Posts Widget](http://jameslao.com/2009/12/30/category-posts-widget-3-0/)

Answer (score 0):

The link building / article-directory site like [adset.org](http://adset.org)

use the [Userpro](http://codecanyon.net/item/userpro-user-profiles-with-social-login/5958681?s_phrase=&s_rank=14) from codecanyon.net to handle all there member Signups/Login.

Then you can let people write posts direct in wordpress backend, and approve them or you can use a plugin like "Frontend Publishing Pro" also from codecanyon.net, and let users post from front end.